# How to install plugins in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I install CKEditor 5 in my project by npm:

> npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic

Then i follow the Doc to install some plugins  eg : **alignment**

[See the Alignment plugins install Doc](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html)

> npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment

And i change my code like this:

```
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignment';

ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    plugins: [ Alignment],
    toolbar: [ 'alignmentDropdown']
} )
.then( ... )
.catch( ... );
```

Then something went wrong:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src/alignmentui.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/dropdown/button/createbuttondropdown' in '/Users/wangyao/project/katabat-demo/ckeditor5/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/src'
```

**I think it is because of the version，
On the official website，i saw the `ckeditor5-build-classic` [version info](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/editor-classic.html)** :
[image]

**And the the plugin `Alignment` [version info](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/api/alignment.html) :**[image]

1. Am I doing this wrong?
2. is CKEditor 5 incomplete because of the alpha version ?
3. It is appropriate to use CKEditor 5 in alpha version ?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (19.09.2018):** The [text alignment](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html), [table](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/table.html), [highlight](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/highlight.html) and [font size/family](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html) features are all available for installation. The situation about which @KingOfSocket asked was a temporary situation when some of these plugins were under development. Check out those feature guides to learn how to install them.

---

**OUTDATED**: You were unfortunate to find the [alignment feature](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment) before its first official release. It doesn't work because the 0.0.1 version is published only to satisfy our development environment's requirement that a package we work on is on npm (actually, this is [Lerna's requirement](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/878)).

The first working version of the alignment feature will be released together with CKEditor 5's 1.0.0-beta (within a ~month). For now, you can find its demo in the **nightly** docs (see [Text alignment](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html)). You can also try to build the editor with it, but you will need to set up the [CKEditor 5's development environemnt](https://ckeditor5.github.io/docs/nightly/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/contributing/development-environment.html).

Comment: PS. We're going to mark nightly docs so people are not that confused what they are seeing (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/866). Let us know what you think!

Comment: It looks like ckeditor 5 is a overkill of all the great features we enjoyed in ckeditor 4. Just for the sake of recent ECMA standards in Javascript, you refactored all code-base and left the community at shock.

Comment: We didn't refactor anything. CKEditor 5 is a completely new product, solving a different set of requirements, with a completely different architecture, etc.

Comment: So is ckeditor 5 at all usable by now? For new users its the first choide being on the website. Unfortunately it seems Plugins still cannot be installed. (e.g Table)

Comment: The [text alignment](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/text-alignment.html), [table](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/table.html), [highlight](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/highlight.html) and [font size/family](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/font.html) features are all available for installation. The situation about which @KingOfSocket asked was a temporary situation when some of these plugins were under development. Check out those feature guides to learn how to install them.